# Diablo 3, one purchase for Mac *and* Windows, or one for each?

Tags: diablo-iii

Today, Diablo 3 went open beta for the weekend, which means I'm finally able to test it on my iMac. I know Blizzard put a lot of work into both platforms so I don't expect them to behave all that different in terms of performance, but I still want to test both.

But a question popped up, and I can't seem to find an answer to this anywhere, perhaps it is implied.

The pre-purchase, or the actual purchase when that comes around, will that be "access to the game" or "access to the game on Windows", and then a separate purchase for Mac?

Basically, when I purchase the game, do I have to pick my platform or do I just purchase access and can switch back and forth at my own whim?

Does anyone know?

Comment: Just adding this [link](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/4963739/Diablo%C2%AE_III_Open_Beta_Weekend-4_19_2012#blog) for information about D3 open beta.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you log in to the Battle.Net site and choose to Download Games, you can download either Windows or Mac client from there.  So it would be purchase once and you can use it on either platform.

Comment: And you're sure this is not just now under the beta? The purchase is thus access to the game, and not access to the game *on a specific platform*? Note that I know that World of Warcraft was "access to the game" because I played that and know that I can download and install the game client on a mac and just log in, but since Diablo 3 has a single player part, there could be licensing differences for *that part*.

Comment: Diablo 3 does not have a non-Battle.Net single player, all play is through Battle.Net.

Comment: OK, I didn't know that, but in my defense I have tried to stay away from the game until now, perhaps I should just let it be until the launch day then, since I can switch back and forth. I was afraid I had to choose platform, and thus wanted to test which is better (if it makes a difference that is.)

Comment: When you purchase the game digitally from Blizzard, you don't even get an option of which platform you are purchasing, so it must give you both.

Comment: I wondering how fast you get those questions about diablo @bwarner it's unbelievable fast the answers =P Adding some information: everyone who is gonna play Diablo is mandatory the creation of his nickname for his battle net account (they create it instead of showing your real name/last name in battle net chat)

Comment: PS: Correcting the name. it's [BattleTag](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/4132437) Not nickname as I said before. BattleTag is a new way for players to identify themselves and communicate on Battle.net®

Answer (score 5):

Blizzard is unique in its cross-platform love: it has bundled Windows and Mac versions together on hybrid discs for over a decade. **Your retail or direct download purchase lets you play on either platform.** When you buy *D3*, you're really paying for the Battle.net account CD key. Once it's linked, you can re-download Mac *and* Windows clients any time you want, but your key will only work on one concurrent installation.